# Circular constraining and "missing constraints" error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am playing around with the circular positioning provided by `ConstraintLayout`. In the below sample app I have a `TextView` centered on the screen and an `ImageView` circularly constrained to the `TextView` with a radius of **50dp**s and an angle of **45 degree**s. It should be fully constrained as there are no more XML attributes starting with `app:layout_constraintCircle`, so  I assume I have fully declared its intended position. However, Android Studio gives me the following warning on the `ImageView`:

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

Running the application proves me right as the constrained view is in its correct location and does not jump to the start of the layout.

So my question is: am I missing any additional constraints or is Android Studio somehow bugged not recognizing circular constraining as valid?

Example XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/hello_text"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="45"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="50dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having tried this myself I could just say this is bug with android studio lint.

Since there is angle and radius defined `ImageView`'s position relative to the `TextView` is fixed.

For now you could just suppress the lint error by adding

```
tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
```

to the ImageView.

Better to report this in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com), under

```
Android Public Tracker > App Development > Android Studio > Lint
```

---

Actually something similar (lint error) occurred to me when using Parcelize, which is reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138278617).

Comment: So it is indeed a bug. I will submit a report soon, thanks for the link.